# SQL Server: Case statement is displaying Msg 8115, Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query which is throwing:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

Query:

```
Select 
    @Fee = Case 
              When IsNull(Fee, '') = '' Then 0.00 
              Else Fee 
           End
```

`@Fee` is of type `Money`, and `Fee` is `Varchar` type.

I have also observer that for following types of data in `Then` clause no error is being displayed.

```
Select @Fee = Case When IsNull(Fee, '') = '' Then 1 Else Fee End
Select @Fee = Case When IsNull(Fee, '') = '' Then 1.0 Else Fee End
```

So only for values `0.00` or `0.0` in `Then` clause I am getting error.

I have also tested with below query and worked fine:

```
Select @Fee = Case When IsNull(Fee, '') = '' Then Cast(0.00 as money) Else Fee End
```

And more interesting thing is that, as per data we have in table, `Then` part of the `Case` statement will never be executed. Please help me understanding this behavior of `Case` statement.

Comment: does Fee is column ? If it is than please give sample data of fee column..

Comment: Yes @Dhaval Fee is column of type Varchar and all i have is value 2 in the column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have played around this and this is what happens:

```
DECLARE @v VARCHAR(20) = '1'
SELECT CASE WHEN '' <> '' THEN 0.00 ELSE @v END col1 INTO tempTable
```

When you will execute the above query you will see error but the table will be created and the type of the column created `col1` is `numeric(2,2)`. If you change to `0.0000` the type will be `numeric(4,4)`. This means that actually the type of an expression depends on that value. Also `(2,2)` means that you can store only values with length 2 and everything goes after dot(`.12`, `.25` etc). So it can not cast `1.00` to `numeric(2,2)` because the type doesn't allow to have digits before dot.

The best rule here is to always return the same types from different paths of case expression.

This is from Microsoft about return type of case expression (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

> Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in
>   result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression. For more
>   information, see Data Type Precedence (Transact-SQL).

This is about type precedence where you can see that `numeric` precedes `varchar`(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx). So the return type of your case expression becomes `numeric(2,2)` and this is the answer to your question.

I will also give you an advise: never store `money` values in `varchar` columns. Always store values in appropriate type(there are so many types available that all your needs will be satisfied).

Answer (score 1):

You have a `CASE` expression that returns two different datatypes - that's **always** a really bad idea....

```
Select 
    @Fee = Case 
              When IsNull(Fee, '') = '' Then 0.00 
              Else Fee 
           End
```

- When `Fee` is in fact NULL, you return `0.00` - a numerical value
- When `Fee` (`varchar`) is NOT NULL, then you return that value - a string

Since both cases are assigned to one and the same `@Fee` variable - SQL Server must coerce these into the same datatype - whatever `@Fee` dictates (`money` in your case).

And for some reason, in the case of `Fee` being NOT NULL, that seems to fail at times.

So the point is: whenever possible, return the **same datatype** from all your possible values in a `CASE` statement - and do so **explicitly** (using a `CAST` or `CONVERT`) - don't force SQL Server to handle this for you

Comment: Thanks @marc_s, but when i am using 1.0 instead of 0.00 error is not being displayed. Please help me to understand this behavior on the basis of data.

Answer (score 1):

the code will reproduce your issue

```
DECLARE @Fee MONEY
DECLARE @test VARCHAR

SELECT @Fee = ISNULL(@test, 0.00)

Select @fee
```

but this one is the fix

```
DECLARE @Fee MONEY
DECLARE @test VARCHAR

SELECT @Fee = ISNULL(@test, '0.00')

Select @fee
```